# How can I find a view in a navigation view by ID from an activity?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, findviewbyid

I have an activity layout which calls to another xml file as a header. I'd like to get a reference by id of an image view set in the `nav_header_main`, yet I can't reach it.

activity_main:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header_main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageButton
        android:background = "@drawable/roundedbuttonwhite"
        android:id="@+id/LogoButtonView"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logoimg" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Note that `nav_header_main` is being called in the `activity_layout`.

I tried to set an OnClickListener in the activity, but I get a NullException, simply because I can't reach to that ImageButton view from the activity.

```
logoImageButton = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.LogoButtonView); //Returns null
logoImageButton.SetOnClickListener(this);
```

Is there any way to go around it and to get a reference? Seems like I miss a simple thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 View hView =  navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
 TextView nav_user = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.nav_name);
 nav_user.setText(user);`

Comment: As said, I sure miss something simple. Could not make the connection by myself.. Thanks a lot! Another [source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/66405/how-to-change-a-textview-in-navigationview-app-headerlayout-xamarin-android).

Answer (score 2):

```
nav_draw.getMenu().findItem(R.id.LogoButtonView).setVisible(false);
```